# fade out when above a variable

Tags: slide, fade

hello I am having trouble with a small piece of code. I hope for a div to slide right(push left) and fade out at the same time when a "var" goes above 3, I thought 'if' might work. 
Can anyone see any problems with my syntax?  thanks for you help. : )

```
  if(lineNum >= 3) {
    $("#pic2-div").animate
({
    "left": "+=150px",
    "opacity": "0.25"
    }, 1000);
```

thanks to shoaib!

i found this worked for me.

```
if(lineNum >= 3) 
{
  $("#pic2-div").animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=150",
  }, 1000  );
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(lineNum >= 3) 
{
  $("#pic2-div").animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=150",
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Code to execute after animation complete.
  });
});
}
```

Hope this helps.